# github jekyll page build keeps failing

Tags: jekyll

I am maintaining a github page using jekyll, and today I noticed my build keeps failing no matter what actions I take (e.g., upload files, delete files, making slight text changes in files). I am attaching the error message from "Build with Jekyll":

> Error: Logging at level: debug Configuration file: /github/workspace/./_config.yml GitHub Pages: github-pages v229 GitHub Pages: jekyll v3.9.4 Theme: jekyll-theme-primer Theme source: /usr/local/bundle/gems/jekyll-theme-primer-0.6.0 Requiring: jekyll-github-metadata Requiring: jekyll-seo-tag Requiring: jekyll-paginate Requiring: jekyll-sitemap Requiring: jekyll-gist Requiring: jekyll-feed Requiring: jekyll-redirect-from Requiring: jekyll-coffeescript Requiring: jekyll-commonmark-ghpages Requiring: jekyll-github-metadata Requiring: jekyll-relative-links Requiring: jekyll-optional-front-matter Requiring: jekyll-readme-index Requiring: jekyll-default-layout Requiring: jekyll-titles-from-headings GitHub Metadata: Initializing... Source: /github/workspace/. Destination: /github/workspace/./_site Incremental build: disabled. Enable with --incremental Generating... EntryFilter: excluded /package.json EntryFilter: excluded /CHANGELOG.md EntryFilter: excluded /LICENSE EntryFilter: excluded /Gemfile EntryFilter: excluded /README.md Reading: _posts/2013-08-14-blog-post-2.md Reading: _posts/2012-08-14-blog-post-1.md Reading: _posts/2015-08-14-blog-post-4.md Reading: _posts/2199-01-01-future-post.md Reading: _posts/2014-08-14-blog-post-3.md EntryFilter: excluded /assets/js/plugins EntryFilter: excluded /assets/js/vendor Reading: _teaching/2014-spring-teaching-1.md Reading: _teaching/2015-spring-teaching-2.md Reading: _publications/2015-10-01-paper-title-number-3.md Reading: _publications/2010-10-01-paper-title-number-2.md Reading: _publications/2009-10-01-paper-title-number-1.md Reading: _portfolio/portfolio-2.html Reading: _portfolio/portfolio-1.md Reading: _talks/2023-11-07-presentation.md Reading: _talks/2023-11-28-presentation.md Reading: _talks/2023-01-06-talk.md Reading: _talks/2022-03-31-presentation.md Reading: _talks/2024-02-02-presentation.md Reading: _talks/2024-02-09-presentation.md Reading: _talks/2023-09-27-talk.md Reading: _talks/2024-02-06-talk.md Reading: _talks/2023-11-26-presentation.md Reading: _talks/2023-10-10-presentation.md Reading: _talks/2023-12-05-presentation.md Generating: JekyllRedirectFrom::Generator finished in 0.025965185 seconds. Generating: JekyllOptionalFrontMatter::Generator finished in 0.00022088 seconds. Generating: JekyllReadmeIndex::Generator finished in 0.000534733 seconds. Generating: Jekyll::Paginate::Pagination finished in 4.859e-06 seconds. Generating: Jekyll::JekyllSitemap finished in 0.00036056 seconds. Jekyll Feed: Generating feed for posts Generating: JekyllFeed::Generator finished in 0.00065649 seconds. github-pages 229 | Error: undefined method `excerpt_separator' for #<Jekyll::Page @name="404.md">

Sorry I have close to zero knowledge of CS so I can't interpret what is going on.

Making any updates result in

pages build and deployment / build (dynamic) Failing after 24s

pages build and deployment / report-build-status (dynamic) Successful in 2s
Details

pages build and deployment / deploy (dynamic) Skipped

Comment: Do you use explicite configuration for .github/workflows/ or you don't have such file?

Comment: @maikhel I don't have such files: my page is based on https://github.com/academicpages/academicpages.github.io

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like the build is broken due to GitHub update of Jekyll to v3.9.4, you can see more information on [academicpages GitHub issue](https://github.com/academicpages/academicpages.github.io/issues/1878) and [Jekyll repo issue](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/9544).

**Quick-fix solution**

Remove `excerpt: ...` config commands from top of the files:

- `_pages/404.md`
- `_pages/about.md`
- `_pages/non-menu-page.md`

And from your other custom files that utilise this command.

Comment: The issue is tracked in the Jekyll repo issue. It looks like the proposed fix made in that ticket broke something else. So, it is still broken as of 02/14/2024.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Moving to Github Actions resolved the issue for me:
https://jekyllrb.com/docs/continuous-integration/github-actions/

Comment: This didn't work for me. Do you have to do something specific after moving to Github actions? On Create jekyll.yml I got ```jekyll 3.9.4 | Error:  undefined method `excerpt_separator' for #<Jekyll::Page @name="404.md">```